# Small Linux distro with Ruby

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, livecd, small-distribution, ruby

I have been using Puppy Linux for basic Linux needs, however now I would prefer one that has Ruby included, so that it does not have to be downloaded.

I would prefer a small distro that can run from a CD, smaller size preferred to decrease boot time. What would be a good choice for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Momonga Linux](http://www.momonga-linux.org/) is a Japanese GNU/Linux distribution that features strong support of the Ruby programming language and its usage is strongly advocated. 
One project that is being developed by the Momonga team is a wrapper library that enables user to utilize RPM from Ruby.

Comment: @svnpenn "small distro that can run from a **CD**"

Comment: @svnpenn all Im pointing out is that the answer fits your minimum requirements

Answer (score 1):

Tiny Core Linux is a good option Very Small. At 10 megabytes, Tiny Core is 1/400 to 1/100 the size of the most widely used operating systems in the world (even compared to most Linux distros). That makes Tiny Core flexible enough to be stored and run from usb sticks, a just-about-full CD, or even embedded devices. hardware.

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/intro.html

ruby package is available with this distro, but you may need to make a custom ISO

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet might be to [make your own ISO](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=edit+live+cd+linux&aq=f&oq=edit+live+cd+linux&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.12931&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). That way you can customize it as you want and then burn it to  a CD.

[Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Installing_Ruby#Linux) says

> Ruby comes preinstalled on many Linux systems.

But they dont elabourate.. So I feel you are better off making your own as I suggest above.